# Confusion about IE9's automatic Document Mode behavior

Tags: rendering, internet-explorer-9, doctype, quirks-mode

I'm experiencing a very strange behavior in IE - gasp, right? - regarding Document Mode.

Normally the browser picks this based on doctype and so on, but two separate, untampered-with installations of the same exact version of IE - 9.0.8112.16421 - choose different Document Mode when visiting the same URL. One machine chooses IE9 standards mode, the other chooses IE7 standards.

Anyone have an idea why this might happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical explanation here is that you have different settings for CompatView on the two machines. On the Tools menu, choose "Compatibility View Settings." If they're the same, look in the page's Context Menu > Properties and see if the page is being treated as originating in a different Zone on one of the computers.